# How do I properly retrieve prefs received here (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to allow the user inputted data to be sent to another file and then saved in as part of the list variable;

```
JS File 1:
const var1Element = document.getElementById("var1")
const var2Element = document.getElementById("var2")
const var3Element = document.getElementById("var3")

const myButtonThing = document.getElementById("myButton")

---skipped the user data inputted part; it works.---

myButtonThing.onclick = () => {
    const prefs = {};
    prefs[var1Element.value] = {
         var1: var1Element.value,
         var2: var2Element.value,
         var3: var3Element.value
    }
    chrome.storage.local.set(prefs)
};

JS File 2:

const list = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];

---skipped the createReminder function; it works.---

chrome.storage.local.get('prefs', (result) => { 
    const prefs = result || {};
    for(let key in prefs) {
        const value = prefs[key];
        const newReminder = createReminder(value.name, value.birthday, value.reminder);
        list.appendChild(newReminder);
```

I tried the below earlier for my get and it worked... but I wanted to save multiple user inputs so I decided to not do the below

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["var1", "var2", "var3"], (result) => { 
    let { var1, var2, var3 } = result;
    let newReminder = createReminder(var1, var2, var3);
    list.appendChild(newReminder)
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.